# I want to redirect to a clean URL using ht access?

Tags: php

I have this path in localhost (`localhost/ams/forms/login.php`). I want to redirect for clean url (`localhost/ams/forms/login/`) when I type localhost/ams.

Comment: hey guys! i have this project which redirect to localhost/ams/forms/login.php which redirect when i type on browser localhost/ams. I try to used htaccess for a clean url but i research a lot but no answered help to accomplished the clean url or just i dont want to display .php file extension?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

## This for clear .php from url

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

## this for redirect from old file path to new file path

```
Redirect /olddirectory/oldfile.html http://example.com/newdirectory/newfile.html
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i'm looking for more clean url

Comment: you want when type (localhost/ams).. redirect to (localhost/ams/forms/login/)